# javascript cheat SRC is not working

Tags: javascript, html

On this below code, it is not working as expected, actually, on this code, the variable 'dummy1' and 'dummy2' content is not getting loaded on this page as expected. Any clues?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript On-line Test</title>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.1">
var dummy1 = '<html><body><p>Sample Dummy Piece</p></body></html>';
var dummy2 = '<html><body><font face=\"Arial\"> Strap in Bucko: This ain\'t no JavaScript vacation...</body></html>';

</script>
</head>

<frameset rows="190%,*" frameborder="1" border="1">
<frameset cols="50%,*">
<frame src="MyAPP.html"/>
<frame src="javascript: self.dummy1"/>
</frameset>
<frame src="javascript: self.dummy2"/>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Prefer iFrame instead of frameset, and this code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect that to work? It won't. You can't use src that way.

SRC needs a URL, not a string.

Also, is this source code from 1990? You don't write HTML like this anymore. If you got this from a tutorial it's time to find a new one.

Comment: Isn't URL a string ; )?

Comment: @Teemu I suppose technically, but please let's not confuse Sakthivel.